# Computing spatial (zonal) statistics of gridded data (NetCDF file) for polygons in a shapefile (EU NUTS2 regions)

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, netcdf, spatial-statistics

I have the shapefile of NUTS2 region, with crs:EPSG:4326
I also have a NetCDF file which is a 950*1000 cell.
I want to compute mean per polygon based on the data in the NetCDF file with Python.

I'm following this code (provided by user: Jannis) which works but gives me 'nan' or 'zero' values. Which I think the problem is the coordinate system of my .nc file.
code:

```py
# import packages
import xarray as xr
import rasterio as rio
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterstats as rstats

# load and read shp-file with geopandas
shp_fo = r'../path/to/shp_file.shp'
shp_df = gpd.read_file(shp_fo)

# load and read netCDF-file to dataset and get datarray for variable
nc_fo = r'../path/to/netCDF_file.nc'
nc_ds = xr.open_dataset(nc_fo)
nc_var = nc_ds['var_name']

# get all years for which we have data in nc-file
years = nc_ds['time'].values

# get affine of nc-file with rasterio
affine = rio.open(nc_fo).transform

# go through all years
for year in years:
    # get values of variable pear year
    nc_arr = nc_var.sel(time=year)
    nc_arr_vals = nc_arr.values
    # go through all geometries and compute zonal statistics
    for i in range(len(shp_df)):
        print(rstats.zonal_stats(shp_df.geometry, nc_arr_vals, affine=affine, stats="mean min max"))
        print('')
```

I have tried different approaches to correct the coordinate system or define one for my .nc file but none of them have worked.

```py
nc_ds.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace="True")

clipped = nc_ds.rio.clip(geometries =shp_df.geometry.values, crs=4326)
```

This is also my NetCDF file when I open it with xarray
[image]

How can I correct the coordinate system for my .nc file?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Code should be provided as text in code block. Images are not legible on all devices, and force anyone who wanted to test you code to retype it (unlikely).